# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `' for #<#<Class:>>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods

I'm relatively new to rails and I've been struggling with this for a couple of days.  I'd be much appreciated if you can see where I've gone wrong.

When I view the page in the web browser I get the following message:

> Showing C:/Users/Matt/Documents/GitHub/Outputer/app/views/studies/index.html.erb where line #8 raised:
>
> undefined method `studies_path' for #<#:0x6b03808>
>
> 8: <%= form_for @new_study do |f| %>

**studies_controller:**

```
def index
    @line = current_user.lines.find_by_id(params[:line_id])  
    @machine = @line.machines.find_by_id(params[:machine_id])  
    @studies = @machine.studies.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @new_study = @machine.studies.build
end

def create
    @study = current_user.lines.machines.study.build(params[:study])
    if @study.save
        flash[:success] = "Study created"  
    else
        flash[:error] = "Error : Invalid study description"  
    end
    redirect_to :back
end
```

**index.html**

```
....
<section>
<%= form_for @new_study do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "New study description..." %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
</section>
....
```

**Study Model**

```
....
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :machine
    belongs_to :line
    attr_accessible :avg_speed, :avg_uptime, :avg_yield, :description, :duration, :is_active, :start_time, :stop_time, :line_id

    validates ....

    has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
    ....
end
....
```

**rake routes:**

```
....
save_line_machine_study PUT    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/:id/save(.:format) studies#save {:has_many=>:machines}
line_machine_studies    GET    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies(.:format)          studies#index {:has_many=>:machines}
                        POST   /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies(.:format)          studies#create {:has_many=>:machines}
new_line_machine_study  GET    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/new(.:format)      studies#new {:has_many=>:machines}
edit_line_machine_study GET    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/:id/edit(.:format) studies#edit {:has_many=>:machines}
line_machine_study      GET    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/:id(.:format)      studies#show {:has_many=>:machines}
                        PUT    /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/:id(.:format)      studies#update {:has_many=>:machines}
                        DELETE /lines/:line_id/machines/:machine_id/studies/:id(.:format)      studies#destroy {:has_many=>:machines}
....
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users
resources :lines, :has_many => :machines,  only: [:index, :edit, :destroy, :show, :create] do
    resources :machines, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] do
        resources :studies 
    end
end
```

If I remove the form the page works fine which would suggest its in the form.  I've tested the controller commands in the console and they all appear fine - I can create a new study object.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

When you use `form_for` with a model instance, it defaults to the `POST` action for that controller which would be your `studies_path`. This is usually mapped to `create` in the controller.

From the looks of it, you need to add a route in `routes.rb` to handle that post request (see resources). You will also need a `create` method in your studies controller.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is a good guide for learning the basics of routing in rails.

Comment: Thanks.  So I have a create route - I've edited the post and added the code.  At the moment I can't get the form to load when viewing index.html - I've not gotten as far as trying to submit it yet so I don't think I'm hitting the create controller yet.

Comment: Even though you have a method for create, you don't have an actual route for it. Nothing is telling it to use that method. The form is trying to load with `studies_path`so either add the route to routes.rb, or specify a different path for the form to use.

Comment: I've added the contents of routes.rb.  I may have got something wrong  here but my understanding is that `resources :studies` should create all the routes including create

Comment: It does but it creates them within the scope of :lines. so you wouldnt ever have a studies path. It would be a `lines_machines_studies_path`. If this is how you want it to stay, I recommend updating your form_for so that it uses `lines_machines_studies_path`

Comment: Thanks - so for anyone reading this struggling with the same thing I've used `<%= form_for [@line, @machine, @new_study] do |f| %>` because of the nested resources.

Answer (score 1):

Although a missing route is the most common reason for that (not-very-helpful) error, it can also be raised if one or both sides of a has_many/belongs_to relationship is missing or is incorrectly defined. Another place to look is a form field for an attribute that doesn't exist in the related model.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= form_for @new_study %>` is equivalent to `<%= form_for @new_study, url: studies_url %>`. As your routes are defined differently, you need to pass the url you'd like to submit the form to to the `url` parameter (find `form_for` in the Rails API docs to see what other options it takes).

Three level deep nesting is kind of ugly to maintain, so I'd suggest the following:

```
resources :users

resources :lines do
  resources :machines
end

resources :machines do
  resources :studies 
end
```

These `shallow` routes are much nicer to maintain. There's also a `shallow: true` option on nested resources calls, see the docs.

In your case:

```
# With the current setup
<%= form_for @new_study, url: line_machine_studies_path(@line, @machine)
# Same, my preference
<%= form_for [@line, @machine, @new_study] %>

# If you make your routes shallow,
# @line is not nescessary, as @machine holds all information about associations

<%= form_for @new_study, url: machine_studies_path(@machine) %>
# Same, my preference, what I would do
<%= form_for [@machine, @new_study] %>
```

General suggestions:

- `@study` is preferred over `@new_study`. `@study.new_record?` will tell you whether the object is a new record if you need.
- There's no `has_many :...` option on resources routes as far as I'm aware
- Google `rails shallow routes` for more info. Keep nesting to two levels. Think about only what information you really require when creating objects and keep the URLs and url helpers as slim as possible.

Comment: These examples probably need a `do` in their `form_for`.